# How can I permanently set ulimit -n 8192 in Centos 7?

Tags: centos, ulimit, centos7

I would like to permanently set the open file limit for all users in Centos 7, but there seems to be a lot of conflicting information out there on the googles.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unless they've done something really wacky (if so, blame systemd) that's all set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

```
*    soft    nofile 8192
*    hard    nofile 8192
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to increase file limit for system service you'll have to edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/SOME_SERVICE.service`

add `LimitNOFILE`,

```
[Service]
...
LimitNOFILE=8192
```

and run `systemctl daemon-reload` to activate changes.

Please refer to [systemd execution Limit directives documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LimitCPU=)

Comment: https://ma.ttias.be/increase-open-files-limit-in-mariadb-on-centos-7-with-systemd/

Comment: I think this solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It could be done by creating new config file in: /etc/security/limits.d/ (to be on safe side when upgrading etc). For example:

```
/etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf
```

with content as written before by sysadmin1138:

```
*    soft    nofile 8192
*    hard    nofile 8192
```